# Small company network SSL -> xampp + SSL + subjectAltName

Tags: tls, openssl

i have issue about SSL cerf. in small local network.
One of the computers is server with apache (xampp), there is basic website called **site.test**

When i created certification, all works only when im located on LOCALHOST and address is marked **site.test**

If i wanna connect from another computer and ping via cmd SERVER PC address i got answer from server, so its connected between. But i cannot connect with address: **site.test** and when i type IP addr of pc (192.168.0.151 - because its local) my CHROME (78.0.3904.97) give me err:

NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID (local) 
 AND 
ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID(another PC in network)

I'm also configured http-vhosts.conf AND htt-ssl.conf + hosts file to define localhost is **site.test**

I think there is some problem with subjectAltName, but how to fix? because im my cert. log ive seen all DNS what im using in my local network.

Thanks. Have a nice day.

```
---------------------------------------[ hosts ]---------------------------------------

127.0.0.1       site.test


---------------------------------------[ http-vhosts.conf ]---------------------------------------

        <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin --hidden just here on forum--
            DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
            ServerName site.test
            ServerAlias *.site.test

            ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
            ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
        </VirtualHost>

        <VirtualHost site.test:443>
            ServerAdmin --hidden just here on forum--
            DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
            ServerName site.test


    ServerAlias *.site.test
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/server.key"

        ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
        ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost 192.168.0.151:443>
        ServerAdmin --hidden just here on forum--
        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
        ServerName site.test
        ServerAlias *.site.test
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/server.key"

        ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
        ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
    </VirtualHost>



---------------------------------------[ CERT LOG ]---------------------------------------

    Certificate:
        Data:
            Version: 3 (0x2)
            Serial Number:
                64:c7:90:f4:85:83:99:6e:8f:f7:35:3d:4c:3d:0b:dc:16:ba:14:a4
            Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
            Issuer: C = US, ST = NY, L = New York, O = "Example, LLC", CN = site.test, emailAddress = test@example.com
            Validity
                Not Before: Nov 17 15:43:03 2019 GMT
                Not After : Nov 16 15:43:03 2020 GMT
            Subject: C = US, ST = NY, L = New York, O = "Example, LLC", CN = site.test, emailAddress = test@example.com
            Subject Public Key Info:
                Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                    RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                    Modulus:
                        00:e1:69:5a:97:07:37:0d:f4:4e:7c:3b:33:74:5d:
                        47:8f:54:19:41:55:72:e6:6f:6e:81:03:b8:82:a2:
                        20:c2:0c:9d:6d:de:61:98:cc:a6:ff:f0:40:8c:47:
                        b4:de:bf:c1:16:3b:ec:51:e3:e6:82:7e:27:e3:45:
                        98:2e:c3:9f:b2:25:51:8f:22:9d:f0:81:eb:aa:bb:
                        60:c7:9a:50:92:af:bc:cb:be:3c:91:5b:11:f6:0e:
                        b6:ec:1e:61:53:23:a8:b3:f0:fc:da:a9:9e:85:69:
                        26:12:7c:fe:90:5c:f3:2f:ed:36:a0:f1:54:74:41:
                        36:2d:6b:8e:b5:a2:87:44:3a:0c:94:86:d5:a5:68:
                        71:fa:29:25:c1:fc:c2:62:f2:10:6f:01:df:60:16:
                        8f:6b:9c:0e:61:55:39:29:04:8f:36:0b:92:4e:a3:
                        e8:4c:0a:35:2e:5e:bb:58:bd:94:bd:bb:bc:5f:bb:
                        59:83:69:e6:af:25:11:04:b8:7d:b6:77:a5:bb:30:
                        87:d3:cf:f9:cc:6b:70:34:58:d5:6b:8d:21:9e:33:
                        11:e5:54:57:e5:57:41:e9:b3:4a:de:15:f7:15:a9:
                        76:8b:54:d3:aa:05:bd:17:13:47:77:67:ec:ba:36:
                        44:bc:03:11:eb:c7:a1:e8:28:9d:7b:fe:24:8e:48:
                        e5:35
                    Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
            X509v3 extensions:
                X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                    15:E5:68:E5:86:07:9D:EC:FD:92:2C:44:1C:1D:74:49:D9:12:25:5F
                X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                    keyid:15:E5:68:E5:86:07:9D:EC:FD:92:2C:44:1C:1D:74:49:D9:12:25:5F

                X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                    CA:FALSE
                X509v3 Key Usage:
                    Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
                X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                    DNS:site.test, DNS:192.168.0.151, DNS:192.168.0.151:443
                Netscape Comment:
                    OpenSSL Generated Certificate
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
             60:1a:3a:07:60:3c:66:f4:d7:ab:3e:49:3f:99:d6:f0:12:6d:
             6f:da:49:aa:17:a5:8a:8c:02:2a:77:73:c1:47:47:c5:aa:1a:
             ba:56:0f:dc:59:1d:0c:df:3b:33:20:c7:b5:c9:44:4e:51:d8:
             b2:ad:e7:1f:34:2e:f3:9f:e3:e7:4c:20:84:19:92:d7:da:9f:
             12:d9:0e:5c:41:6b:10:28:14:58:90:da:56:2c:18:a5:17:71:
             f5:2f:88:0b:51:2f:48:2e:01:79:a3:2b:7d:8b:c5:2e:a9:75:
             c1:cc:4b:9b:58:61:9d:16:06:b8:d5:0e:35:2f:11:dd:44:c1:
             db:dd:f5:81:2d:f5:9e:bd:5c:78:21:28:3f:0c:18:24:77:a2:
             15:c5:55:c2:0f:d4:cf:b1:13:26:32:a4:11:09:4f:50:6a:6d:
             ef:6b:d5:ab:7c:4c:1c:98:52:e0:04:f7:8f:8d:59:81:21:69:
             47:50:4b:4e:89:32:22:72:09:3e:b4:c0:a4:1d:30:c6:0a:9e:
             17:b7:7d:0b:6a:ca:cc:ae:9d:53:4b:f3:61:d5:19:d8:80:e5:
             22:c2:8e:5f:0e:b2:5e:9a:7e:bb:f7:7e:86:04:0b:2d:d6:ad:
             89:78:64:81:76:15:94:16:17:3f:b2:b5:02:02:4f:9d:77:46:
             31:56:bb:33
```

Im trying to show you situation by pics.

HERE IS ACCESS FROM LOCALHOST PC TO SAME SERVER:

[image]

HERE IS ACCESS FROM LOCALHOST PC WITH PC ADDRESS TO SAME SERVER:
+ NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

[image]

EDIT:

extension=openssl in php.ini
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so in httpd 
All uncommented.

Comment: In short: if the certificate is issued for a domain you need to access it by domain and not by IP address. Otherwise you get the problem that the name in the URL (i.e. the IP address) does not match the name in the certificate (the domain). And while you've tried to add the IP to SAN you added it as domain name and not IP address.